# Tensorflow softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits versus tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y*tf.log(yhat), reduction_indices = 1))

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am following the multi-layer perceptron example from here: https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples and I am confused about the function `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` and how it relates to `tf.nn.relu` and `reduce_sum`. Suppose I declare a net work with:

```
x   = tf.placeholder('float',[None,24**2])
y   = tf.placeholder('float',[None,10])
w1  = tf.Variable(random_normal([24**2,12])
w2  = tf.Variable(random_normal([12,10])
h   = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x,w1))
yhat= tf.matmul(h, w2)

'''
  cost function
'''
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_corss_entropy_with_logits(logits=yhat, labels=y))
```

Shouldn't the above be the same as:

```
x   = tf.placeholder('float',[None,24**2])
y   = tf.placeholder('float',[None,10])
w1  = tf.Variable(random_normal([24**2,12])
w2  = tf.Variable(random_normal([12,10])
h   = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x,w1))
yhat= tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h, w2))

'''
  cost function
'''
cost = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y*tf.log(_hat),reduction_indices=1))
```

But when I train using the first construction, my accuracy is around `95%`, the second method yields `1%` accuracy, so clearly it's more than just "numerical instability" correct?

For the complete example see: https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/multilayer_perceptron.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did some quick research. I added this above line 62 in the `multilayer_peceptron.py` file and printed it at line 87

`cost_v2 = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y*tf.log(tf.nn.softmax(pred)),1))`

At the first batch, it came out as `nan` because `pred` actually contains quite a few zeros after the softmax. I'm guessing that the cross entropy ignores the zeros and just proceeds with the sum based on this: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9302/the-cross-entropy-error-function-in-neural-networks